# How to truncate variables listed within a method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I need to keep my code less than 80 characters per line. I have this here:

> ```
> function Contact(first, last, street, city, state, zip, phone, email, birthdate, photo) {
> ```

How do I shorten it? I'm fairly certain my only option is to shorten every variable because these are parameters for a method and are required to be there in order for the method to work.

Comment: You can hit enter at any time between variables ~ https://jsfiddle.net/ku4fzbo6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments can be separated by newlines, which is what I prefer to do when there are way too many of them to list on a single line:

```
function Contact(
  first,
  last,
  street,
  city,
  state,
  zip,
  phone,
  email,
  birthdate,
  photo,
) {
  // function body
```

But in this sort of situation I'd strongly prefer passing a single object to `Contact` instead, eg

```
const contact = new Contact({
  first: 'foo',
  last: 'bar',
  // ...
});
```

Then the function only needs to declare one parameter.

```
function Contact(data) {
  // reference data.first here
```

Comment: IMO, a limit of 80 characters is silly given the size of modern screens. Sometimes reducing line length improves readability (like here), but if you have long descriptive variable names (which are a good idea) you'll frequently run into the limit. Maybe consider increasing the character limit.